# Parse instanceid from SNS topic to Lambda trigger

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a requirement so that SNS topic generated from Cloudwatch alarm and then SNS triggers a Lambda function to change a tag of a EC2 instance.
Following is the code I have so far but I am getting records key error. Ca someone please help. I think I am not sure how to get the instance id from the message here.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snsClient = boto3.client('sns')
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    instance_id = message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]
    tagResc = boto3.client('ec2')
    ret = tagResc.delete_tags(
        Resources=[instance_id],
    Tags=[{'Key': 'Availability' }]
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]
```

returns:

```
{u'name': u'InstanceId', u'value': u'i-abcd94b3583afdc'}
```

So you'll need to use:

```
instance_id = message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by using the below code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Set the instance ID of the EC2 instance to connect to
    sns_message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    instance_id = sns_message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']
    print("Instance ID got from SNS:", instance_id)
```